# Dart/Flutter - controller error in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, controller

It is necessary that when scrolling vertically one / any column on a smartphone (Android), the entire vertical (internal) `ListView.builder` scrolls.

In VScode `debage` mode, line 36 `extentBefore = _controllerList.offset;` throws the error `_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 108 pos 12: '_positions.length == 1': ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views.)`. This error is thrown both when you move your finger and when you press the `floatingActionButton`.

In the `release` mode, only one column is scrolled vertically (not the entire array), but when shifting the array with the <+> key, everything works fine (and the entire array is scrolled, and the value of the entire array's vertical offset is remembered).

Many thanks in advance for my complete code with fixes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'lb_lb_fb_2',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double extentBefore = 0;
  double squareSize = 40.0;

  var cells = List.generate(500, (j) => List.generate(500, (i) => '$j\n$i'));

  ScrollController _controllerList = ScrollController();

  void _onScrollEvent() {
    extentBefore = _controllerList.offset;
    _controllerList.jumpTo(
      extentBefore,
    );
    _controllerList = ScrollController(
      initialScrollOffset: extentBefore,
      keepScrollOffset: true,
    );
    setState(() {});
    print('---_onScrollEvent - extentBefore = $extentBefore');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controllerList.addListener(() {
      _onScrollEvent();
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controllerList.removeListener(_onScrollEvent);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          //
          ListView.builder(
            itemCount: cells[0].length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int indexF) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: squareSize,
                //
                child: ListView.builder(
                  controller: _controllerList,
                  itemCount: cells.length,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      height: squareSize,
                      width: squareSize,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      color: (indexF + index) % 2 == 0
                          ? Colors.grey
                          : Colors.amber,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(cells[index][indexF]),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          extentBefore = extentBefore + 50.0;
          _controllerList.jumpTo(
            extentBefore,
          );
          _controllerList = ScrollController(
            initialScrollOffset: extentBefore,
            keepScrollOffset: true,
          );
          setState(() {});
          print('---floatingActionButton - extentBefore = $extentBefore');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I read all the documentation on `ListView.builder` and `controller`, tried to find an answer on the Internet and here, but did not find the cause of the error (exception) and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In these lines

```
_controllerList = ScrollController(
            initialScrollOffset: extentBefore,
            keepScrollOffset: true,
          );
```

you are trying to reassign a controller that is already initialized and attached to a view.

I am not sure what the idea is here, but typically you initialize a ScrollController in initState(), call to dispose it in dispose() (which you did not do and it's another problem), and never reassign it.

Comment: I tried different things - my code is one of dozens of options that all did not work. Works correctly only on the "+" key, but I need a swipe of my finger.
Can you rewrite my code without error? I am willing to pay not to continue the research work - plus a huge thank you. :-)
-
Я пробовал разное – мой код один из десятков вариантов, которые все не работали. Правильно работает только на клавише «+», но мне нужно движением пальцем.
Вы можете переписать мой код без ошибки? Я готов заплатить, чтобы не продолжать научно-исследовательскую работу – плюсом к огромному спасибо. :-)

Comment: It's very hard to do what you want. You can have two nested SingleChildScrollView widgets - it works fine with a small number of cells, but at 250,000 cells it's unusable. You can also try to have 500 synchronized ScrollControllers, but it's also probably too slow. I don't know your requirements, but there may be a completely different solution that does not involve rendering so many widgets.

Comment: I kind of did it, but I had to make several layers (several ListView.Bilder, image.memory, 2D scrolling Foundation, etc.) and connect all this with master and slave controllers both vertically and horizontally.